# Is there any IDE integration for JBoss AS 6?

Tags: java, ide, jboss, jakarta-ee

We have switched to JBoss 6 to make it possible to use a wider range of Java EE technologies. We chose JBoss because of its small memory footprint compared to other application servers, so we have no other choice.

Do you know any developer tools that can be integrated with JBoss AS 6?

Thanks in advance

Jonathan Frank

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse and [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) play nice.

Answer (score 1):

See [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools), there is also [JBoss Developer Studio](http://www.jboss.com/products/devstudio/).

Comment: Having used JBoss Developer Studio I would recommend against it

Comment: Why? Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

JBoss 6 will run with the WTP server definition for 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss 6 will work well with Eclipse IDE 3.6.2 Helios download [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr2) (I recommend)

Then you will need to download JBoss Tools to use its features (JBoss Tools 3.2.2 for Eclipse Helios is recommended)

To install JBoss Tools, start up Eclipse 3.6.2 Helios then: 
Help > Install New Software... > 
and add this URL: 
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/helios/

Answer (score 0):

[Jetbrains' Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/java_ide.html) Ultimate Edition too has an excellent support for JBoss and development.